# Uncountable Sequence of Functions in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ let

$$||f||_{\infty} = \text{ess}\sup_{x \in A}|f(x)|.$$

> A remark was stated that if we have indicator functions $f_{\alpha} = \mathbb{1}_{\{x \in [\alpha, \alpha + 1]\}}$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$,  then any sequence of functions $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ where $||f_{\alpha} - f_{\beta}||_{\infty} = 1$ and $\alpha \neq \beta$ is uncountable in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

I don't quite see how this is obviously uncountable, and as a result I've tried to go about forming a contradiction:

Suppose $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ a countable collection in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $||f_{\alpha} - f_{\beta}||_{\infty} = 1$. So, I want to show that essential sup cannot be 1 if $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ is countable, i.e. there exists some set $Z$ which contains points giving $||f_{\alpha} - f_{\beta}||_{\infty} = 0$ with $m(Z) > 0$, where $m(\cdot)$ is Lebesgue measure. Not sure about how I should go about constructing such a set?

Comment: I may be wrong, but the family is uncountbale since it is labelled by real numbers ($\mathbb{R}$ is an uncountable set), and if $\alpha \neq \beta$, then you immediately obtain that the supremum of the distances of the two indicator functions is always 1, so I don't see why you should create a contradiction

Comment: If you are confused, draw the graphs of $f_\alpha := \mathbb 1_{[\alpha,\alpha+1]}$ for a few $\alpha$.  Then compute $\|f_0 - f_{1/2}\|_\infty$.  If you do not get answer $1$, show us your calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this remark is more so getting at whether you have a good understanding of the esssup rather than how $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ is uncountable. In otherwords, if $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ uncountable then $||f_{\alpha} - f_{\beta}||_{\infty} = 1$.

Moreover, as has been stated, $\{f_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}$ is uncountable by construction of $\mathbb{R}$. We take that as is without proof. Now, for the second part, let us assume $\alpha \neq \beta$ and take apart the esssup definition:

$$||f_{\alpha} - f_{\beta}||_{\infty} = \text{ess}\sup|f_{\alpha}(x) - f_{\beta}(x)| = \inf\left\{b \in \mathbb{R} : m\left(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : |f_{\alpha}(x) - f_{\beta}(x)| > b\}\right) = 0 \right\}$$

If $b < 1$, then we can always find a value $x$ which satisfies the inequality. This is due to $\{f_{\alpha}\}$ being uncountable. If say $b = 1/2$ and for some $
\alpha$ and $\beta$ we get 0, we can just fix $\alpha$ and find some $\beta$ which gives 1, always. Then we have the set $\mathbb{R}$. This doesn't have measure 0.

If $b \geq 1$, then we have the $\emptyset$, which does have measure 0.

Thus, we have

$$\inf\{b \in \mathbb{R} : b \geq 1\} = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you stated the remark correctly. I suppose it should be formulated the following way: Let $f_\alpha = 1_{[\alpha,\alpha+1]}$. Then the family $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}$ is uncountable and satisfies $||f_\alpha - f_\beta||_\infty = 1$ for $\alpha \neq \beta$.

Concerning your formulation of the remark, any countable subcollection of $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}}$ yields a contradiction because for $\alpha \neq \beta$ it always holds that $||f_\alpha - f_\beta||_\infty = 1$. So concretely, $\{f_1, f_3\}$  is countable and $||f_1-f_3||_\infty =1$.